# How can I run a java class with a relative path from Ant?

Tags: java, ant, path

I have a File definition in a java class that has a main method and that I would like to be able to run both from the Eclipse run menu as well as from  an Ant build file using a relative path.

This works only when running the main method from the Eclipse run menu:

```
private static final File location = new File("./implementation/src/xml/data");
```

This works only when running in Ant:

```
private static final File location = new File("./src/xml/data");
```

The project is structured like this:

```
MyProject
    |
    |
implementation
   |       |
   |       |
  src    build.xml
```

This is the Ant task:

```
<target name="run">
    <java classname="test.XMLCreator" classpathref="compile-classpath" >
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${classes}" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

I understand that this is because in Ant, the path is relative to the location of the build file, and inside a java class it's relative to the root directory of source.

Is there a way to override the base directory inside an Ant task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's several ways you might do this.  Perhaps the simplest is to specify a relative value for the `dir` attribute in your [`java`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) task, for example:

```
<java classname="test.XMLCreator" classpathref="compile-classpath" dir=".." fork="true">
```

You'll need to also use `fork` for that to work, which may have other side effects.

On your specific question: many tasks support the `dir` attribute, some use nested filesets, so there you would have to specify the directory on the nested element.

Another approach is to execute a target using the [`ant`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/ant.html) task.  The directory specified there will be used as the basedir for all tasks in the target.